# Is there an intended watching order for the Lego and Rebels Star Wars shorts on Disney Plus?

Tags: star-wars

I am talking about these short series:
[image: Lego Star Wars Freemaker Adventures Shorts, Lego Star Wars The Resistance Rises, Star Wars Rebels Shorts, and Lego Star Wars All-Stars Shorts]

Comment: They're all set at different points in the tinelime. Just watch them however you feel like watching them.

Comment: Note that the three lego shows are non-canon ("Legends") whereas the Rebels Shorts is part of the accepted canon.

Answer (score 3):

These collections of shorts are not consistent stories to be played in order. They jump around in time, location, and sometimes even in characters. Having watched the Rebels shorts, I believe each episode would be spread throughout the regular Rebels seasons.

TLDR; No, there is no particular order to watching these as they do not hold to a consistent, consecutive time period themselves.